# Pass Single Value from a User Control to Containing Page's Code Behind in C Sharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I need to pass a value from the onload event of a user control to the onload event of the parent page. I have found this code on stackoverflow but I can't seem to get it to work/adapt it:

```
Public Property SomeValue() As String
Get
    Return textbox1.Text
End Get
End Property
```

The value I need to pass is a single int from a database.

```
 conn.Open();
 reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
 if (reader.Read())
 {
     shoppingCartHeadID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["shoppingCartHeadID"]);
     hfShoppingCartHeadID.Value = shoppingCartHeadID.ToString();
 }
 reader.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I opted to create a separate public class to call and control the cart. This turned out to be much more efficient and cleaner code!

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to *pass* anything. Just create a property on your user control and access it from the page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userControlValue = UserControl.UserControlValue;
}
```

Comment: Yep I've done that but I get the error: The name cart does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Did you make the Cart property public?

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
Public Property SomeValue() As String
Get
Return textbox1.Text
End Get
End Property
```

Looks like this in C#:

```
public String SomeValue {
 get{ return textbox1.text}
}
```

I think by the way that the child user control should set a property, what the parent user control should read.

```
//child
public string DatatoShare{get;set;}
protected override Onload()
{
DatatoShare = "Whatever you want"
base.Onload()
}

//parent
private ChildUserControl child;
public string NeedChildsData()
{
return child.DatatoShare
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its not the fine way, but if you realy now what you are doing there, you can try it with an property

mayby something like this:

```
//child uc class
...
public string MyValue { get; private set; }

//... loaded (...)
{
    ...
    this.MyValue = "Value";
}

// Parent uc class
//... loaded (...)
{
    ...
    string childValue = this.ucChildControl.MyValue;
}
```

Comment: The trouble is I really don't know what I'm doing! I've just starting to learn .net c#. I can see where your coming from but I can't get it to work in practice. The UC code is fine. but it's getting string childValue = this.ucChildControl.MyValue; to play nicely in the parent page. My UC class name is called cart but I'm getting an error saying there's no definition for cart.

Comment: Make sure that cart is declared as public so you can access it from the page.

Comment: cart is declared like this > public partial class cart : System.Web.UI.UserControl. I took out partial and it made no difference.